# Solve for $a$,$b$ given the system is differentiable at $x=3$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The question is per the title with

$f(x) = 6x-a   $ when $x   \leqq 3$

$ f(x) = bx^2  $ when  $x>3 $

I set the 2 equations equal to get $9b + a =18 $ for $x=3$
but now I have $1$ equation and $2$ unknowns.
I know the solutions are $a=15$ and $b=1/3$ but how do I get my second equation?

Comment: You have only used continuity thus far. Use differentiability, and the fact that the derivative at the point  3 is unique.

Comment: Why do you equate the two parts of the function?

Comment: If I set the derivatives equal, then I get $ 2bx=6 $ which is not correct.  Confused on next step.

Comment: Actually, not sure now why I equate the two parts.  I guess they could NOT intersect and still be differentiable at $x=3$

Comment: But then you have computed the value of b correctly, since it should be equal to 1, where the textbook is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuity at $x=3$, gives

$$18-9b=a $$

the differentiability at $x=3$, yields to

$$\lim_{3^-}\frac {6x-18}{x-3}=\lim_{3^+}\frac {bx^2-9b}{x-3} $$

or
$$6=6b $$
thus
$$b=1 \;\;,\; \;a=9$$

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.  You need $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ to be continuous at the joint $x=3$  The result is $b=1, a=9$ with $f(3)=9$ on both sides of the joint and $f'(3)=6$.  With the book answer of $b=\frac 13$ the derivative above $3$ is $2$ and the derivative just below is $6$

Answer (score 0):

Let's call these two functions:

$$f_{1}(x)=6x-a ,\quad x\le 3$$
and
$$f_{2}(x)=bx^2 ,\quad x>3$$

Using differentiability:

$$f_1'(3)=f_2'(3)$$

Using continuity:

$$f_1(3)=f_2(3)$$

Which should give you:

$$a=9,\, b=1$$

Comment: I see this now.  Thank you.